# Prevent bubbles from overlapping in D3 bubble chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, data-visualization

I'm creating a bubble charts with D3 v5 by following this example https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/bubble_tooltip.html (only replacing the callback for a promise when fetching the csv). So far it works great.

Now I need to be able to apply a physics effect to the visualization where the bubbles won't overlap each other, I believe what I need is called [forceCollide](https://d3indepth.com/force-layout/#forcecollide). I've been trying for a while but I can't seem to get it to work. This is the code I use for the creation of the bubbles:

```
// Before I set dimensions, read the data, create x and y axis
// add bubble scales and create tooltips 
// ...

//Add dots
  var nodes = svg
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(data);

  nodes
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "bubbles")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.gdpPercap);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.lifeExp);
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return z(d.pop);
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return myColor(d.continent);
    })
    // -3- Trigger the functions
    .on("mouseover", showTooltip)
    .on("mousemove", moveTooltip)
    .on("mouseleave", hideTooltip);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any solutions for the same